# What is the meaning of the colored bars in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Does anyone know what the colored bars that show up on the left and right hand side of the active pane are supposed to convey? Hovering and/or clicking on them does not seem to reveal their purpose, and my apparently subpar googling skills have failed to turn up any relevant answers.

The screenshot below shows orange and blue, but green and red are often present as well.

[image: jetbrains ide active pane]

Comment: VCS changed/added lines markers.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to versionning. In webstorm (maybe depending of your config) :
- green for added
- blue for modified
- red for removed